# When do I need to run update-snapshot in blueprint development

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-blueprint

I'm developing a new blueprint for internal teams as a kickstarter for common requirements. I'm attempting to put this blueprint on a pipeline in Git***Lab***—not to be confused with Git*Hub*.

Should the pipeline call `npm run update-snapshots` at some point? Should snapshots be "updated" prior to committing (and merging to `master|main`) by the committer?

I don't see blueprint examples like JHipster Native taking any GitHub actions for snapshots in that pipeline.

I have not fully grok'd this snapshot practice yet. It's mostly undocumented in JHipster blueprints, but appears to be a practice of unknown provenance or origin to this Java engineer, possibly from Mocha. But I'll be looking more into it.

Comment: I do have a working pipeline now in GilLab (had to call `npm link` for the tests to pass). I'm still puzzling over the `updateSnapshots` full use case in a development workflow and pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Snapshots should be updated and committed with the changes to git.

It's based on [jest-snapshots](https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing) with the purpose of making easy for the reviewer (and the developer) to take a glance at the generated files names or the generated file content.

You can see [this PR](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/21070/files#diff-e14b2239d0cf3dd66097a314d44af71e24b3a3d545af4d8a8b062c4ec8349e05) as example.
The liquibase changelog snapshot is shown and we can review the generated xml at a glance.

Another examples is [this other PR](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/21308/files#diff-084cdb70b2b0324c71139784c1ac9b9bc63d7bddec69b5ce8e36df5f74ea0c26).
The generated file renamed from `TestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory.java` to `SqlTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory.java`